# Criar um AlertDialog com um EditText do tipo "number" - Android

Tags: android, edittext

Bom dia Pessoal, estou com um problema no meu Alert:
Nele possuo um EditText, só que não consigo declarar o EditText com o tipo numeros(android:inputType="number"). Alguma ideia?
Segue o código do alert:

```
public void exibirMensagemEdt(String titulo, String texto){

    AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = new AlertDialog.Builder(TelaCardapio.this);
    mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
    mensagem.setMessage(texto);
    // DECLARACAO DO EDITTEXT
    final EditText input = new EditText(this); 
    mensagem.setView(input);
    mensagem.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.getText().toString().trim(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    mensagem.show();
     // FORÇA O TECLADO APARECER AO ABRIR O ALERT
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```

Comment: Se não me engano é só usar o método `setRawInputType` na instância do seu EditText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `setRawInputType()` da seguinte maneira:

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Ou você também pode usar o método `setInputType()` passando o mesmo argumento. Com este método se o teclado já estiver aberto irá reiniciar o teclado, o que não acontece com `setRawInputType()`.

Comment: Vlw Luidne, funcionou aqui do jeito que você falou.

Answer (score 0):

final EditText editQuantidade = new EditText(this);
        editQuantidade.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);